# How can I make a TextField appear if the user selects the "Other" value from the SelectField?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, bootstrap-5

I'm working with React and Bootstrap 5 to create a Meteor application.  I want a text box to appear if the user selects the "Other" option from the drop down menu.

this is what I've tried so far

```
const [showTextField, setShowTextField] = useState(false);

const handleSelectChange = (name, value) => {
  console.log('Selected value:', value);
  setShowTextField(value === 'Other');
};

<SelectField name="type" label="I FOUND/LOCATED THE FOLLOWING" onChange={(value) => handleSelectChange('type', value)} />

{showTextField && (
  <Form.Group controlId="otherDescription">
    <Form.Label>Other Description:</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter other description" />
  </Form.Group>
)}
```